File Import Dialogue Box runs in editor but not from button on sheet
I am trying to import data from CSV files into Excel.
I want to open the file explorer so that I can choose a file to import csv data from.
When I run it in the VBA Editor it opens the file explorer, I can open the file, it imports the data.
When I run it from a button in the sheet I get:

File dialog could not be initialized. Please make sure you have the appropriate references enabled.

Sub ImportCSV()
    Dim selectedFile As String
    Dim csvFilePath As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    #If Mac Then
        ' AppleScript for macOS
        selectedFile = MacScript("return POSIX path of (choose file of type {""public.comma-separated-values-text""} default location (path to desktop folder))")
    #Else
        ' Windows API for Windows
        With Application.fileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .title = "Select a CSV File"
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show = -1 Then
                selectedFile = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
    #End If

    If selectedFile <> "" Then
        ' Import data from the CSV file
        csvFilePath = selectedFile
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add ' Add a new worksheet to import data
        
        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvFilePath, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True ' Assume CSV uses comma as delimiter
            .Refresh
        End With
        
        MsgBox "Data imported successfully from " & csvFilePath, vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
    ' Clean up
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub

I tried Application.GetOpenFilename which doesn't run even in the editor.

Where the code you show exists? In a standard module or in a sheet code module? What kind of button do you try using? How do you "assign the macro to a button in the sheet"?

Works just fine for me.

What OS do you use? MAC or Windows?

Read this link where it says that the Macscript function is deprecated and no longer supported. And links to an old SO post which says roughly the same. Maybe this is happening now.
